# How to count record in particular (namespace,kind) in google datastore in node.js?

Tags: node.js, gcloud, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using gcloud npm module. thanks in advance.

I tried out so much but didn't get anything.

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm looking and not finding an appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a query on that entity Kind and count the result.

```
var query = ds.createQuery('EntityKind');

ds.runQuery(query, function(err, entities, info){
    if(err) { 
    // deal with error in here
    }

    var total = entities.length;

    // You should check if there are more result 
    // and maybe run the query again until there are no more result

    if (info.moreResults !== gcloud.datastore.NO_MORE_RESULTS) {
        // More result
    }

});
```